# getting the names of elements in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I have some checkbox inputs like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" class="filter"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" class="filter"/>
...etc...
```

I'm trying to write a function where any time a checkbox is selected, it generates a string with all the names concatenated. Here's what I have so far:

```
$('.filter').click(function(event){
    var filters = $('.filter').toArray();
    var fstr = "";
    for (f in filters)
    {
        fstr = fstr+","+f.name;
    }
    alert(fstr);
});
```

The names keep coming up as 'undefined', though (i.e. the alert returns `,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined`). How do I access the names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how it's meant to be done:

```
$('.filter').click(function (event)
{
    var fstr = '';
    $('.filter[name]').each(function ()
    {
        fstr += ',' + $(this).attr('name');
    });
    alert(fstr);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out the proper jquery syntax, and what's more this one actually works :)

Comment: There is no `.name()` method, you have to get the name like any other attribute, using `.attr()`. You may have seen `.val()` used, but that is a special function primarily for getting the logical value of form elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get what you're after, like this:

```
$('.filter').click(function(event){
  var names = $('.filter').map(function () { 
    return $(this).attr("name"); 
  }).get().join(',');
  alert(names);
});
```

Just change `$('.filter')` to `$('.filter:checked')` if you want a list containing only the checked ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.filter').click(function(event){
    var filters = $('.filter').toArray();
    var fstr = "";
    for (f in filters)
    {
        fstr = fstr+","+filters[f].name;
    }
    alert(fstr);
});
```

Why are you doing it that way anyway?

```
$('.filter').click(function(event){
    var str = '';

    $('.filter').each(function () {
       str += $(this).attr('name') +",";
    });

    alert(str);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($filters) {
    $filters.click(function(event) {
        var filters = $filters.toArray();
        var fstr = [];
        for (var i = filters.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
            fstr.push(filters[i].name);
        }
        fstr = fstr.join(",");
        alert(fstr);
    }
})($('.filter'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(f).name`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `$(elem).attr("name")`?

Comment: By `elem` i mean any element. So in this case you'd use `$(f)`... - still undefined?

Comment: He's using `for in`, `f` is simply the property's key, not value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the convert to array is your problem, try:

```
var filters = $('.filter');
for(var nI = 0; nI < filters.length; nI++)
filters.eq(nI).attr('name');
```